# Mac Pro AirPort Super Slow

Tags: mac, performance, airport, mac-pro

My internet connection on my Mac Pro is terrible. I hardwired a lap top to my modem and did the Cox speed test and scored very very fast. I then did the test on that laptop wirelessly, and again, I scored very very high. So my provider and my wireless router are out as suspects.

My Mac Pro is consistently scoring very low. And it shows in performance. Anyone have any ideas why this is?

Comment: Is the MBP slow on both WIFI and Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably, "Because Mac Pro towers have...um...*less than ideal*...antenna placement". If you open it up and look where the antennas are, you'll probably find that they face out the bottom of the unit.

For a temporary test, try getting your tower out from under your desk, and put it on its side on top of your desk, with its bottom pointing toward your wireless router. See if that fixes things.

If it does, you might consider buying some other kind of external antenna solution. Maybe get a pair of desktop dipoles and run the antenna leads through a spare PCI slot fence.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of signal strength readings (in dB) are you getting? (Option click the airport menu item to get additional info about the signal.)

Answer (score 0):

There were also some issues with cables that were connected to the wrong pins inside the case. Your model is probably affected by this issue. To see if you’re affected you can follow the steps at http://nobblynoel.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/mac-pro-2009-bluetooth-fix/

Also note that it hasn’t necessarily something to do with Bluetooth. Sometimes the cables are just not wired up in the right manner.

See also [Why is the network speed on my Mac Pro (early 2009) so slow?](https://superuser.com/questions/134904/why-is-the-network-speed-on-my-mac-pro-early-2009-so-slow) for a related question.